# On Qt how is it possible to set a 3 columns layout with 33% each?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui, qlayout

i have a 3 columns layout and i'm struggling to find a solution in order to set 3 fluids columns on 33%.

Comment: horizontal stretch set to `1,1,1` in qtdesigner or set stretch to 1 for each of the indices 0,1,2

Comment: Ok thank you, i have understood the logic of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

> [void QBoxLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int stretch = 0, Qt::Alignment alignment = 0)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addWidget)
>
> Adds widget to the end of this box layout, with a stretch factor of stretch and alignment alignment.
>
> The stretch factor applies only in the direction of the QBoxLayout, and is relative to the other boxes and widgets in this QBoxLayout. Widgets and boxes with higher stretch factors grow more.
>
> If the stretch factor is 0 and nothing else in the QBoxLayout has a stretch factor greater than zero, the space is distributed according to the QWidget:sizePolicy() of each widget that's involved.
>
> The alignment is specified by alignment. The default alignment is 0, which means that the widget fills the entire cell.

You would need to use the stretch factor equally based on this short documentation. Therefore, you would write something like this:

```
myLayout->addWidget(myWidget1, 1);
myLayout->addWidget(myWidget2, 1);
myLayout->addWidget(myWidget3, 1);
```